# useEffect is not immediate in ReactJS also if I use an async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sqlite, async-await, use-effect

Basically every time I do a operation to my database (sqlite3) it does not render immediately on the page, but I have to click on some other component to update or I have to refresh the page/reset the server

This is the snippet I quite use in every page component:

```
const fetchData= async()=>{
        let updatedVector= await API.getUpdate();
        for (let i = 0;i<props.courses.length;i++){
            for (let j=0;j<updatedVector.length;j++){
                if(props.courses[i].code===updatedVector[j].code){
                    props.courses[i].current= await API.getSpecificData(props.courses[i].code);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchData();
    },[fetchData])
```

It does update on the database but takes some time to update on the component, is there any way to update like in an immediate way? Or I have to refresh the application.

---

EDIT: I passed the setState too, but yet I have to click at least twice on the component link and then I have my update:

```
//get updates
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("triggered")
        const fetchData= async()=>{
            let updatedVector= await API.getUpdate();
            for (let i = 0;i<props.courses.length;i++){
                for (let j=0;j<updatedVector.length;j++){
                    if(props.courses[i].code===updatedVector[j].code){
                        props.courses[i].current= await API.getSpecificData(props.courses[i].code);
                    }
                }
            }
            props.setCourses(props.courses)
        }
        fetchData();
    },[fetchData])
```

Comment: You must use `useState` to update state, manually changing `props.courses` will not be saved nor rendered. Also `fetchData` must be declared outside of render function (or `useCallback`) and accept courses as parameter, otherwise new `const fetchData = () => ...` is created every render, and `useEffect` always sees changed dependency. Pass setter from `useState` as `useEffect` dependency, and call setter with callback, because `useState` value changes every render, but not captured in callback.

Comment: Ok this give me some ideas, but what I show in the page it's from another component. So I have to use props. Is there any way to use state with props? Also, I change the value of props every time I do a query

Answer (score 0):

Is **props.courses[i].current** a useRef?

if so try using useState to handle your data, u won't have a re-render problem.

Comment: It is a state but in the initial page, I pass courses in the component then

Comment: Try passing setState as a prop aswell and use the setState to update your data

Comment: Thank you. I did try and it is a bit faster, but yet I don't have a live update :/

Comment: I don’t think you need to loop ur data. 
Try using a spread operator 

props.setCourses([…updatedVector])